# Sipml5 errors when running inside of Phoenix frameworks

Tags: javascript, webrtc, elixir, phoenix-framework

When I am running sipml5 in Phoenix framework. I got errors in below. The problem is that I have no error when I use sipml5 without frameworks. I tested this in Flask and Django too. But I got the same errors again.

```
    GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/conn.js 
call:35 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/SIPml-api.js 
call:60 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/conn.js 
SIPml-api.js:19 YOUR ARE USING DEBUG CODE. PLEASE USE CODE UNDER 'release' FOLDER or check https://code.google.com/p/sipml5/wiki/FAQ#How_to_reduce_the_size_of_the_scripts_before_deploying for more information on how to amalgamate the code.
(anonymous) @ SIPml-api.js:19
tsip_dialog_generic.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ACCEPT' of undefined
    at tsip_dialog_generic.js:19
(anonymous) @ tsip_dialog_generic.js:19
SIPml-api.js:16 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/SIPml.js?svn=230 
(anonymous) @ SIPml-api.js:16
(anonymous) @ SIPml-api.js:12
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_param.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_api.js:16
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_qos.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_api.js:16
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_common.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_api.js:16
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_webrtc4all.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_common.js:40
SIPml-api.js:16 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySIP/src/tsip_api.js?svn=230 
(anonymous) @ SIPml-api.js:16
(anonymous) @ SIPml-api.js:12
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_defaults.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_common.js:40
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_session_roap.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_session.js:681
tsk_api.js:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySAK/src/tsk_base64.js?svn=230 
tsk_api_add_js_script @ tsk_api.js:13
(anonymous) @ tsk_api.js:17
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_session.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_common.js:40
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_session_jsep.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_session.js:681
tmedia_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinyMEDIA/src/tmedia_session_ghost.js?svn=230 
tmedia_api_add_js_scripts @ tmedia_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tmedia_session.js:681
tsk_api.js:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySAK/src/tsk_buff.js?svn=230 
tsk_api_add_js_script @ tsk_api.js:13
(anonymous) @ tsk_api.js:17
tsk_api.js:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySAK/src/tsk_string.js?svn=230 
tsk_api_add_js_script @ tsk_api.js:13
(anonymous) @ tsk_api.js:17
tsk_api.js:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySAK/src/tsk_fsm.js?svn=230 
tsk_api_add_js_script @ tsk_api.js:13
(anonymous) @ tsk_api.js:17
tsk_api.js:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySAK/src/tsk_md5.js?svn=230 
tsk_api_add_js_script @ tsk_api.js:13
(anonymous) @ tsk_api.js:17
tsk_api.js:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySAK/src/tsk_param.js?svn=230 
tsk_api_add_js_script @ tsk_api.js:13
(anonymous) @ tsk_api.js:17
tsk_api.js:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySAK/src/tsk_ragel.js?svn=230 
tsk_api_add_js_script @ tsk_api.js:13
(anonymous) @ tsk_api.js:17
tsdp_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySDP/src/headers/tsdp_header_A.js?svn=230 
tsdp_api_add_js_scripts @ tsdp_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tsdp_header.js:52
tsdp_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySDP/src/headers/tsdp_header_Str.js?svn=230 
tsdp_api_add_js_scripts @ tsdp_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tsdp_header.js:52
tsdp_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySDP/src/headers/tsdp_header_O.js?svn=230 
tsdp_api_add_js_scripts @ tsdp_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tsdp_header.js:52
tsdp_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySDP/src/headers/tsdp_header_V.js?svn=230 
tsdp_api_add_js_scripts @ tsdp_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tsdp_header.js:52
tsdp_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySDP/src/headers/tsdp_header.js?svn=230 
tsdp_api_add_js_scripts @ tsdp_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tsdp_api.js:19
tsdp_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySAK/src/tsk_api.js?svn=230 
tsdp_api_add_js_scripts @ tsdp_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tsdp_api.js:17
tsdp_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySDP/src/tsdp_message.js?svn=230 
tsdp_api_add_js_scripts @ tsdp_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tsdp_api.js:19
tsip_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySIP/src/dialogs/tsip_dialog_register.js?svn=230 
tsip_api_add_js_scripts @ tsip_api.js:12
(anonymous) @ tsip_dialog.js:1100
tsip_api.js:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:4000/src/tinySIP/src/dialogs/tsip_dialog_invite.js?svn=230
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Unfortunately, phoenix (in my case) couldn't support separate folders which is required to run of api. So for this reason you should need to rewrite your code and use apartly.